# Generate a certificate signing request based on an existing certificate with x509v3 extensions

Tags: ssl, tls

With openssl I am trying to generate a CSR using an existing cert that contains X509v3 extensions, in particular SAN.  I am able to create the new CSR by running

```
openssl x509 -x509toreq -in certificate.crt -out CSR.csr -signkey privateKey.key
```

However, when I run

```
openssl req -text -noout -verify -in CSR.csr
```

I don't see any of the X509v3 extensions that are included in the certificate.  Is this possible?

Comment: Using OpenSSL, you would add the desired X509v3 extensions, including SANs, when the CSR is signed by a CA into a certificate; the extensions to appear in the certificate do not come from the CSR itself.

Comment: +1 for showing me how to quickly generate a CSR from an existing certificate.

Answer (score 1):

From `man x509`:

> BUGS
>
> Extensions in certificates are not transferred to certificate requests
>   and vice versa.

which suggests that it is not possible.

Comment: I belive this bug has now been addressed, with openssl 3.0.0 you can use 'copy_extensions' option to get the alternative names carried over. [ https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-x509.html#copy_extensions-arg ] Example : openssl x509 -x509toreq -copy_extensions copyall -inform DER -in myapp_cert.cer -signkey my_private.key -out myapp-new.csr